# How to get the version of a standard golang package and update it?

Tags: go

I looked into go list but couldn't find a flag that does this. https://golang.org/pkg/math/ has a Round function but it's not found in my local install.

Comment: For updating a package you can use `-u` with `go get` command to install a package

Comment: Probably your Go version on local is < 1.10.

Comment: Consider installing the Go documentation package, if your distribution provides it. This way you always have a local copy of the docs matching your version of Go, and it is also available offline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

golang.org always documents the latest released version of Go. See https://golang.org/doc/devel/release.html for the release notes. [math.Round was introduced in 1.10](https://golang.org/doc/go1.10#math).

Answer (score -2):

You should update the go package for your platform to the latest available.